# How to add the Content-Length,Content-Type and Last-Modified to the HTTP Response Message Header

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse

How to add the Content-Length,Content-Type and Last-Modified to the HttpResponseMessage  Header using .net.

I need to append the all these values manually to the response after adding these fields i need to return the response from the server.
I have tried to adding these fields in fallowing way

```
httpResponse.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", item.Size.ToString());
httpResponse.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", item.ContentType);
```

But it throwing the exception as

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

If i am adding like this

```
httpResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Length", item.Size.ToString());
httpResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Type", item.ContentType);
```

I am  getting the fallowing error

> "Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
>   HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
>   content headers with HttpContent objects."

Please any one help me to add these fields to the HttpResponsesMessage .

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding header to http response in an action inside a controller in asp.net/mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094652/adding-header-to-http-response-in-an-action-inside-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Have you initialized `httpResponse`?

Comment: yes, I have initialized http response

Comment: I don't want to use the Http Context

Comment: Have you initialized `item`?

Comment: What type of content `item` holds? Have you initialized `httpResponse.Content` propety?

Comment: no I have not initialized the httpresponce.content, How to initialized that one. @YuriyRozhovetskiy

Comment: @user3436437 it's depends on what is item payload

Answer (score 13):

You basically need to initialise Content first.  For example:

```
var content = "this is some content";
var response = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = new StringContent(content)
};
response.Content.Headers.Add(@"Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
```