# How to use js to save the content in the browser to local?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, download

I'd like to generate a txt file using Javascript whose contents would be a String and link to it to a button so that the button click would generate the file download. The file cannot be stored anywhere as the contents are supposed to by dynamic.

How do i do this ?

Comment: You wont be able to generate it with javascript. You will have to use a server side script.

Comment: If JS is a must, then use it in conjunction with Ajax and maybe a *"dash"* of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot generate a file using javascript.

What you can do however, is do it with a hidden iframe that links to a PHP file. That PHP file should contain the proper headers (`Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition`, etc).

You should find more details here: [Download file through an ajax call php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php)

Comment: I'll have a look at this, reason i want to use javascript is because i'd want the content to be a string parsed from a json response that is recieved only after user clicks on some other button

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'download' and 'data' attribute like this,

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var a = document.createElement('a');

div.appendChild(a);
a.text='download test file';
a.download='aaaabbb.txt';
a.href="data:text/plain," + 'aaaaaaaaaccccccccccccc';
```

```html
<div id="div">aaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also use the blob and click of the a tag, which will popup the download window without user clicking the a tag.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var a = document.createElement('a');

div.appendChild(a);
//a.text = 'download';
a.download='aaaa.txt'
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['iikkkddddlsldfsjlfsdjf'], {type: 'application/text'}));
a.click()
```

```html
<div id="div">aaaaa</div>
```

To save large content you can refer to [How to generate text files and download a zip file in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30952313/6521116)