# How to generate text files and download a zip file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, download, zip, text-files

I would like to know the best way in Javascript (maybe in JQuery) to do the following things without server coding if able :

1. **Generate around 20 text files from sets of objects.**
2. **Zip these files into a ZIP file.**
3. **Download this ZIP file.**

---

### 1. Generate around 20 text files from sets of objects

There are around 20 sets of objects, with around 90 objects in each set of objects. Here is an example of the sets of objects :

```
var cardsPlayer1 = {
  name : "Player 1",
  [
    {nbCopies : 3, name : "Noise"},
    {nbCopies : 1, name : "Parasite"},
    {nbCopies : 2, name : "Sure Gamble"},
    ... (around 90 of these objects)
  ]
};

var cardsPlayer2 = 
  name : "Player 2",
  [
    {nbCopies : 1, name : "Gabriel Santiago"},
    {nbCopies : 3, name : "Pipeline"},
    {nbCopies : 2, name : "Aurora"},
    ... (around 90 of these objects)
  ]
};

... (until cardsPlayer20)
```

The generated text files should be :

*player1.txt*

```
3 Noise
1 Parasite
2 Sure Gamble
...
```

*player2.txt*

```
1 Gabriel Santiago
2 Pipeline
2 Aurora
...
```

...(until *player20.txt*)

### 2. Zip these files into a ZIP file

I would like to ZIP player1.txt until player20.txt into a ZIP file players.zip.

### 3. Download this ZIP file

I would like to download the ZIP file players.zip.

Thank you for your help and your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use some JavaScript zip library eg https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ and a file saver https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/.

`jszip` provides all necessary examples to put files into the zipfile (this covers points 1 and 2). Using `FileSaver.js` is also pretty straightforward as for point 3.

Comment: It looks like very good and simple! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sample code with `jszip` and `FileSaver.js`

```
import JSZip from "jszip";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

let zip = new JSZip();

// API call to get articles
downloadArticles(articleIds).then(function (response) {
  let records = response.articles;

  for (let index = 0; index < records.length; index++) {
    let record = records[index];

    let blob = getTextBlob(record.title, record.body);

    let file_key = index + 1;

    let filename = `${file_key}-${record.title}.txt`;

    zip.file(filename, blob);
  }

  zip
    .generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
    .then(function (content) {
      saveAs(content, "articles.zip");
    });
});
```