# JavaScript: save contents of a div as a .txt but keep formatting

Tags: javascript, html

I found a great tool in [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) that enables one to easily download content from a div.

I've implemented it in one of my projects:

```
 function savehtml() {
  let filename = "firstdraft";
  let blob = new Blob([writtingContent], { type: "text.plain;charset=utf-8"});
  saveAs(blob, filename+".txt");
};
```

This downloads anything in `writtingContent` as a .txt file. Unfortunately, it also downloads the HTML tags for *italics* and **bold** as well as `</br>` for any new paragraphs.

Is there anyway I could format the content of the div `writingContent` so that the .txt file will preserve the formatting without the HTML.

Comment: What is `writtingContent`

Comment: It's just a div Id it could be anything.

Comment: can't do it from code you will need only on user request/event click to save file on hard disk...Imagine situation you go to some website and page create files on your computer that's main point of web platform.

Comment: @tfantina You can always write your own parser.

Comment: But if you want text you need to get the text - in jQuery `$("#writtenContent").text()` for example

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure what you mean, there is no issue with what I have posted above, it will get the text from a div and download it the issue is that the .txt file will contain html formatting like `<br>` `<strong>` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use js to save the content in the browser to local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656067/how-to-use-js-to-save-the-content-in-the-browser-to-local)

Comment: look also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087881/how-to-save-and-edit-a-file-using-javascript

Comment: I'm not sure, those two deal specifically with saving text but I'm curious more about the formatting of the saved file.

Comment: What kind of formatting do you want to preserve? You want your txt file to contain bold text? Because that's not possible. txt files can only contain plain text.

Comment: Sorry @Ivar.  Bold would be nice for some formats, such as .rtf, but for starters I'm just trying to stay simple.  I realize I can't bold and italicize things in .txt files but it should be able to handle a new line without showing the html `<br>`.

Comment: As @mplungjan mentioned, you can use text function of jquery. As mentioned in docs it will, "Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.". [text doc](https://api.jquery.com/text/). That is what you want right?

Comment: The only way to have  and  text in the  file is using the corresponding unicode analogs to the regular characters. You can try to write a converter for them, like https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/

Answer (score -1):

```
let myHtml = `
paragraph 1</br>
paragraph 2</br>
`;
let br = '</br>';
// create regular expression that will target each instance of the text you want to remove
// construct a new RegExp object avoid issues with html syntax
let remove = new RegExp(br,'g');

function parseHtml(htmlSnip){ 
  return htmlSnip.replace(remove, '');
  // this is the same as
  //return htmlSnip.replace(/</br>/g, '');
};

console.log(parseHtml(myHtml));
```

https://codepen.io/mind_inventive/pen/LBxXqv

Comment: this is an example of how you can remove the </br> tags and it was voted down??? why??