# Download file from google drive using javascript and mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, google-drive-api

I want to download file from google drive i am using following code :-

```
    function downloadFile(file) {
        if (file.downloadUrl) {
            var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            xhr.onload = function () {                
                                var response = xhr.responseText;

            };
            xhr.onerror = function () {
                alert("Error");
            };
            xhr.send();
        } else {

        }
    }
```

file successfully coming in binary format in xhr.ResponseText. Now i want to prompt it to user for download. I am new in java script please help me. I am using asp.net MVC 3 framwork.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php) question. The bottom line: "AJAX isn't for downloading files.".

I think that for your case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322848/845443) answer is the best choice.