# Download CSV is not working in Ajax PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I've implemented the ajax download CSV functionality, for that I've used below code. But it's not working. The code is working fine if I use it in plain PHP code but when I use it in AJAX code, the file is not downloading but it's returning values.

**Return Data**

> bla_col1, bla_col2, bla_col3
>  data1, data2, data3

**Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
        url: base_url + "/product/download-csv",
        type: 'get',
        data: {category: category},            
        success: function (response) {},
        error: function (err) {},
        complete: function (result) { 

        }
    });
```

**Laravel / PHP Code**

```
$filename = "my-file.csv";
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
fputcsv($fp, $csvHeadings);
foreach ($csvValues as $csvValue) {
    fputcsv($fp, $csvValue);
}
```

Comment: why you want to use here ajax at all?

Comment: thats the nature of ajax.. what you can do is to save the csv as a file on the server, and return the url to your ajax function - create a hidden link - inject this in the dom and trigger a click event

Comment: @Salman When I run that URL the file is getting downloaded

Comment: Well, you can't use AJAx here. s. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8771353/3179423

Comment: You can't trigger a download with a Ajax request. Your download code also looks wrong. This topic might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request

Comment: @Salman I didn't get this, which html part I need to add?

Comment: Could try [changing it to application type download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23540193/1624318); it should offer the user a dialog asking if they would like to download it or not.