# Downloading files using ajax in WordPress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Is it possible to use WordPress Ajax to download files. I have this function to download the attachment.

```
function download_attachment()
{
    $file_path = $_POST['filename'];
    $file_mime = $_POST['mime'];
    $data['file_path'] = file_exists($file_path);

    try{
        header('Pragma: public');   // required
        header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_path)).' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: private',false);
        header('Content-Type: '.$file_mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_path));    // provide file size
        header('Connection: close');
        set_time_limit(0);
        @readfile("$file_path") or die("File not found.");

    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $data['error'] = $e->getMessage() ." @ ". $e->getFile() .' - '. $e->getLine();
    }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    die();
}
```

It is hooked to WordPress main function with this function:

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_download_attachment','download_attachment');
```

And the jQuery code is this:

```
var data = {
        'function': 'download_attachment',
        'filename': file_path,
        'mime': mime
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(return_data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            parsedData = kalimahJS.parseJSON(return_data);
            window.open(parsedData.url);
        }
    })
```

The end result is 0 displayed on the screen. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: try to remove the suppress at here `@readfile("$file_path") or die("File not found.");` Maybe the file not found, but you hide the error. What happens if you do?

Comment: I tried both but nothing happens. The file does exist and I have placed an absolute path to it and nothing happened.

Comment: try 2 more things. 1st, try to `var_dump($data);` what it contains? because it seems, `json_encode` fails. 2nd. you can also try, what happens, if you call the php directly. set the `$file_path` and `$file_mime` directly in the ajax file, and call that file. if it's ok, then the data is incorrect what you pass throught `$_POST`

Answer (score 2):

Since no one has ever answered this question, specifically for WordPress, I thought I'd share my answer:

Say, I want to offer a log file for easy download to users of my plugin (that's what I'm working on right now). What I'd do, is the following:

**Register the AJAX action**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_daan_download_log', 'daan_download_log');
```

**Create the function**

```
function daan_download_log()
{
    check_ajax_referer('daan-nonce-value, 'nonce');

    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die(__("Hmmm, you're not supposed to be here.", 'my-plugin-name));
    }

    $filename = '/path/to/filename.log';

    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        wp_die();
    }

    $basename = basename($filename);
    $filesize = filesize($filename);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$basename");
    header("Content-Length: $filesize");
    header('Pragma: public');

    flush();

    readfile($filename);

    wp_die();
}
```

**Link to the AJAX action**

You can add this, wherever you need to be able to download the file.

```
<?php $nonce = wp_create_nonce('daan-nonce-value'); ?>

<a href='<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php?action=daan_download_log&nonce=$nonce"); ?>' class="button button-primary">Download Log File</a>
```

Comment: Nice, but..you're not "doing ajax", you're hooking into the `wp_ajax_*` to perform a download. But, using an `<a>` html element, without any Javascript, you're providing a direct link to the hook's output, not really "doing ajax", and the result is the same as a regular link with a hook to provide the (file) content without involving wordpress' theme. 
I mean, it's still a nice way to avoid some overhead for regular links (that will load wordpress' header and stuff), but it's not really Ajax :-)

Comment: That's absolutely, right! But like you pointed out 6 years ago: AJAX isn't for downloading files. That's why I thought I'd provide the closest alternative. :-)

Comment: Yes yes, and I think it's a clever solution also for many other things :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well.

I come here, 2 years later (almost exactly), to post a link to an answer even older, from nearly 5 years ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6668806/1356098

> AJAX isn't for downloading files. Pop up a new window with the download link as its address, or do `window.location = ...`.

*Note: I changed the code to `window.location` as suggested by @yitwail*

Still... I found some useful information here: https://marksdevserver.com/2011/03/10/downloading-file-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following code also

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_download_attachment', 'download_attachment' );
```

Comment: I added and I received the same result.

Comment: can't download data use Ajax.