# Basic form submission with jquery/ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to jquery and ajax. I'm trying to get my first ajax script to work, but it's not working and I need some assistance, please.

I have a php page that is supposed to post to another php page, where the latter will do some processing and get some files to get zipped and download. The user needs to input a starting and ending date, and the second php script will use this information to prepare the data. This functionality works perfectly fine without jquery, but doesn't work when I add jquery.

**What do I want to achieve?** I want to post in the to the same php page and get the post output in a `<div></div>` tag.

My first php page contains (`downloadPage.php`):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<form action="doDownload.php" method="post" id="dateRangeID">
<input id='time1' class='input' name="datefield1" style="text-align:center;"/>
<input id='time2' class='input' name="datefield2" style="text-align:center;"/>    
<input type="submit" value="Download Data" name="submit" id="submitButton">
</form>
<div id="result"></div> <!-- I would like it to post the result here //-->
```

The second page (`doDownload.php`),

```
<div id="content">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $dateVal1      = $_POST['datefield1'];
    $dateVal2      = $_POST['datefield2'];
    if($dateVal1 != $dateVal2)
    {    
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');

        $fullListOfFiles = $downloadFullTmpFolder.$filesList;
        $command = "sudo $ldlib -u myuser /usr/bin/python3 $downloadScriptFile -datadir $gnomeDataDir -time1 $dateVal1C -time2 $dateVal2C -outdir $downloadFullTmpFolder > debug_download.txt 2>&1";
        $output = shell_exec($command);

        $fp = popen('cat '.$fullListOfFiles.' | sudo -u myuser zip -@ -9 - ', 'r');

        $bufsize = 1024;
        $buff = '';
        while( !feof($fp) ) 
        {
            $buff = fread($fp, $bufsize);
            echo $buff;
        }
        pclose($fp);   
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<p>Dates have to be different in order for the download to start.</p>");
    }
}
else
{
    echo("<p>Error: Page called without submit.</p>");
}
?>
</div>
```

Finally, the jquery part in `downloadPage.php`, which if I add it doesn't work anymore (which I'd like to learn how to do right, and [I mainly learned from the manual of jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), the last example in the link)

```
<script>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#dateRangeID").submit(
function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        t1 = $form.find("input[name='datefield1']").val(),
        t2 = $form.find("input[name='datefield2']").val(),
        subm = $form.find("input[name='submit']").val(),
        url = $form.attr('action');
    var posting = $.post(url, { datefield1: t1, datefield2: t2, submit: subm} );

    /* Put the results in a div */
    posting.done(function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find('#content');  // <--- So this turns out to be wrong. Right is only $(data);
        $("#result").empty().append(content);
    });
});
</script>
```

What is wrong in this? Please assist. Thank you.

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Comment: you have in same directory downloadPage.php and doDownload.php right ? your script in at end of the file downloadPage.php ?

Comment: @Laurentiu Yes. The script at the end is for downloadPage.php, and both are in the same directory.

Comment: Why do you need the submit button value ?

Comment: @RajaKhoury I'm not sure whether submit value is necessary, but I did this because `doDownload.php` seeks the value of submit. Please tell me if that's wrong.

Comment: then check your network tab and see what code take and if it is 200 look your response, your code is good but maiby you can take 500 Internal Server Error, or maiby you not have html in your "data" variable from response.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I think it is irrelevant what its value is, because what you need is the values of time1 and time2.

Comment: hjpotter solved the problem partially, and now I can see the messages in case the dates are equal. But the download of in `doDownload()` still doesn't work, while it uses `fread()`. Should I do anything special about it in jquery? Please advise.

Comment: Remove the `<div id..` entirely from your file. Just leave the PHP code in `doDownload`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I did that already since I removed `find()` because it's not necessary anymore.

Comment: Try a cURL call with some parameters on the `doDownload.php` file. See if you are indeed getting an output.

Comment: @hjpotter92 If I remove the jquery code, it works with no problems. Should I still test cURL with that?

Comment: You mean the page `doDownload.php` is starting a download when the ajax code is removed?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes. It works with no problems and downloads if the ajax code is removed. If the input has a problem, on the other hand, it opens a new blank page with the error text, which is the behavior I don't want.

Comment: Seems like the answer was as simple as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6668806/1190388

Comment: @hjpotter92 Actually that's my plan B. I'm planning to repost to download... Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the obvious, you have:

```
var content = $(data).find('#content');
```

where, you're trying to find an element with the ID `content` in one of the following results:

```
<p>Dates have to be different in order for the download to start.</p>
```

or

```
<p>Error: Page called without submit.</p>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what should I do? Remove that div totally?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Just use `var content = $(data);`

Comment: Oh, that fixes the problem partially! Thanks a lot! But the download doesn't work still. The download uses `fread()` to start. Should I do anything special about it!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist For that, you'd need the `application/octet-stream` as header value. You can not output __anything__ else on the page.

Comment: I have to do this in `downloadPage.php`? I do this in `doDownload.php` already.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Then why are you echoing anything in the `doDownload` page?

Comment: I echo in case of failure only. What would you recommend?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist My two cents, if you would like to retrieve only a portion of that remote content you are downloading ( I can see you are using `$(data).find('#content')` where the content div is that portion ) you may be interested in the load(); method -- Read the Loading Page Fragments here : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @RajaKhoury I don't use `find()` anymore now. I'm sorry I don't understand your second statement.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Yes, I can see that. I just thought it may useful for future uses.. Good luck

Comment: @RajaKhoury Thanks... Still hope you could provide help with the download issue.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I'm afraid i am not mature enough to help with that. I haven't used `fread()` in php before. I think hjpotter92 can guide you much better. Sorry

Comment: @RajaKhoury Thanks anyway :)

Comment: hjpotter92 Could you please spend like 5 minutes helping me with this? Thank you for everything you provided already :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist post the `fread` etc. methods you have currently

Comment: @hjpotter92 I did. Please check the question. I simplified it by removing many unnecessary variable definitions that would just make the code longer.