# How to send file to user who use contact form?

Tags: php, ajax

How to return file to user contact form php+ajax on my site?

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return readfile(polychor_file.pdf);
```

Comment: ...Are you asking how to attach your PDF to your email?

Comment: PD of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php

Comment: How to send a file to users who used the feedback form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file through an ajax call php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php)

Answer (score 0):

Did you asking about Send Email with Attachment? If yes, then here is a source on how to "Send Email with Attachment" : https://www.codexworld.com/send-email-with-attachment-php/.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to file return :

```
    $attachment_location = "usaflag.gif";

    if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {

        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Cache-Control: public"); 
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream'");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=usaflag.gif");
        readfile($attachment_location);
        die();        
    } else {
        die("Error: File not found.");
    }
```