Button doesn't execute the ajax call
I've made a form with a qrcode generator. The qrcode gets generated as an svg and beneath the code there is a download button getting generated aswell. When I click on the download button it should usually execute an AJAX call to my php-script. But it doesn't do anything. The network tab in the browser dev tools shows no call made.
Hope someone could maybe explain why this happens and how to fix. I provide the code below. To be clear, there is really nothing happening. I also tried a var_dump in my downloadQrCode php script which didn't get executed
showLinkGenerator.html.php (view with button generation and ajax)
// Downloadfunktion für QrCode
        $('#pm_publish_content_form_dl_button').on('click', function () {
            $.post(
                '<?= $view['cms_file']->resourceUrl('cms/php/contentpublisher/ajax/admin/downloadQrCode.php') ?>',
                {},
                function (data) {
                    let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/eps'});
                    window.location = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                }
            )
        });

        function generateQrCode() {
            $.post(
                '<?= $view['cms_file']->resourceUrl('cms/php/contentpublisher/ajax/admin/generateQrCode.php') ?>',
                {
                    url: $siteUrl.val(),
                    qrCodeType: $('#pm_publish_content_form_ct_qrcode_dropdown').val()
                },
                function (data) {
                    ($('#pm_publish_content_form_ct_qrcode_dropdown_container')).after(data);
                    $('<div id="pm_publish_content_form_dl_button_container" class="dl-button-container"><button ' +
                        'type="button" ' +
                        'id="pm_publish_content_form_dl_button" ' +
                        'name="pm_publish_content_form[dl_button]" ' +
                        'class="btn btn-form" ' +
                        'style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; margin-left: 5px;">' + trans('link_generation.download', {}, 'contentpublisher_admin') +
                        '</button></div>')
                        .insertAfter($('.qrcode'));
                }
            );
        }

downloadQrCode.php (Script AJAX is making a call to)
use pm\Web\CMS\ContentPublisher\Controller\ContentPublisherAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

require '../../../../bootstrap.php';

global $container;

$request = $container->get(RequestStack::class)->getMainRequest();

$lan = $request->get('lang');

/** @var ContentPublisherAdminController $controller */
$controller = ContentPublisherAdminController::createWithContainer($lan);
echo $controller->downloadQrCode();


ContentPublisherController.php (Function that shall be executed)
public function downloadQrCode() {
        $filePath = __DIR__ . '/qrcode.eps';

        if(!file_exists($filePath)) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
            exit;
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/eps');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . 'qrcode.eps' . '"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));

        return file_get_contents($filePath);
    }


Looks like you are trying to bind your click handler to an element, that doesn't exist yet at the time this code runs. So use event delegation.

@CBroe I see. So if I can trust the JQuery Docs, it's a direct event that's only getting attached to the elements existing when calling the .on method. I understand the problem

Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php

try to use this function like this
// Downloadfunktion für QrCode
    $(document).on('click', '#pm_publish_content_form_dl_button', function () {
        $.post(
            '<?= $view['cms_file']->resourceUrl('cms/php/contentpublisher/ajax/admin/downloadQrCode.php') ?>',
            {},
            function (data) {
                let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/eps'});
                window.location = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            }
        )
    });


$(document): This selects the entire HTML document object. In jQuery, the $ function is used to select elements and create jQuery objects that can be manipulated.

.on('click', '#pm_publish_content_form_dl_button', function () { ... }): The .on() method in jQuery is used to attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. In this case, the event handler is for the 'click' event.

'click': This is the event type being listened for. It specifies that the following function should be executed when a click event occurs.

'#pm_publish_content_form_dl_button': This is the selector for the element to which the event handler is being attached. It is an ID selector (#), meaning it is looking for an element with the ID pm_publish_content_form_dl_button.

function () { ... }: This is an anonymous function that will be executed when the click event occurs on the element with the ID pm_publish_content_form_dl_button. The function is the event handler.


When a user clicks on the element with the ID pm_publish_content_form_dl_button, the anonymous function inside the .on() method will be executed. You can place your custom code inside this function to define what should happen when the button is clicked.

Why should OP try this? Please add some explanation of what you changed and how that would solve the problem. Thanks

That worked, but since I don't really know why that code attaches the event handler although the element gets created later on, I'd refer to @brombeer. Please give some explanation about the code you provided

This example uses event delegation.  read more

See [answer]. While the code may work, it's far better if you actually explain why. That is far more helpful to other readers than a hit-and-hope code dump. You can [edit] your answer. A well explained answer is far more likely to attract upvotes.

This is the selector for the element to which the event handler is being attached...no. The whole point of event delegation is that the handler is attached to document, because that will always exist, whereas the button does not initially exist in the DOM. When the event handler is triggered, jQuery then looks to see if the element underneath document which was the target of the action matches the provided selector. If it does, it continues to run the handler. I appreciate you adding an explanation to your answer, but please at least make sure it's completely accurate :-)

(For further illustration of my point the code is equivalent to this in vanilla JS: document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if (e.target.id == "pm_publish_content_form_dl_button") { $.post(...//etc } }); . Note how the event listener is attached to document, not pm_publish_content_form_dl_button).
